# maven cannot find package atlassian

Tags: java, maven, jira, pom.xml

I am not really a java developer, but I need a plugin for JIRA which is written by java: https://github.com/garaio/jira2vertec-Gateway

You have to build this project using maven. The problem is, if I try to build it using `mvn build install` i get the follwing error message:

> Unresolveable build extension: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:6.3.15 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-jira-plugin:jar:6.3.15 in central (https‍://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 2]

Years ago I've already used maven and as I know, maven know almost all relevant libraries. The plugin which I'm trying to build it, should also work. So I don't know where could be the problem. Is maybe https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 not the right repository? but I didn't change anything in settings.xml of maven.

I'm using apache-maven-3.5.3.

Comment: Check this out https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.maven.plugins/maven-jira-plugin

Comment: @NestorSokil so what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've installed the [atlassian plugin sdk][1] and use the apache maven within this plugin.

But you can use the standard maven and expand the settings.xml file like this:

```
<profile>
  <id>defaultProfile</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
   <repository>
     <id>atlassian-plugin-sdk</id>
      <url>file://${env.ATLAS_HOME}/repository</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>atlassian-public</id>
      <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>atlassian-plugin-sdk</id>
      <url>file://${env.ATLAS_HOME}/repository</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <properties>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

`maven-jira-plugin` 6.3.15 dosen't exist in maven repository

Change  to 5.0.18

```
<amps.version>5.0.18</amps.version>
```

**Edit 1 :**

If you want to use 6.3.15 you should use Spring plugins repository and not the central repository 
[image]

you can do this by

```
<project>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>Spring Plugins</name>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </repository>
</project>
```

for more information if you want to use multiple repository : [Link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html)

Comment: but it dosen't really resolve the problem. I want to use exactly the libraries which are needed. I've tried to configure the settings.xml file according to the guides of maven in order to add a new repository profile https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/. but it still dosen't work.